# TwainDotNet System.TypeInitializationException Error

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add TWAIN support to a program I've been writing for a while. I'm using TwainDotNet from https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet

I've been able to adapt the vb.net example to a new test project without issue. However when I put it into a form in my current project I get an error.

Code:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports TwainDotNet
Imports TwainDotNet.TwainNative
Imports TwainDotNet.WinFroms

Public Class frmDebug

    Private Property areaSettings As New AreaSettings(Units.Centimeters, 0.1F, 5.7F, 0.1F + 2.6F, 5.7F + 2.6F)
    Private Property twain As Twain
    Private Property settings As ScanSettings
    Private Property images As List(Of System.Drawing.Bitmap)

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Twain needs a hook into this Form's message loop to work:
        twain = New Twain(New WinFormsWindowMessageHook(Me))

        ' Add a handler to grab each image as it comes off the scanner
        AddHandler twain.TransferImage,
            Sub(sender As Object, args As TwainDotNet.TransferImageEventArgs)
                If (Not (args.Image Is Nothing)) Then
                    imgScanner.Image = args.Image

                    images.Add(args.Image)

                    'widthLabel.Text = String.Format("Width: {0}", pictureBox1.Image.Width)
                    'heightLabel.Text = String.Format("Height: {0}", pictureBox1.Image.Height)
                End If
            End Sub

        ' Re-enable the form after scanning completes
        AddHandler twain.ScanningComplete,
            Sub(sender As Object, e As TwainDotNet.ScanningCompleteEventArgs)
                Enabled = True
            End Sub
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdSource_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSource.Click
        ' Show the "select scanning source" dialog
        twain.SelectSource()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Error:

```
'Program.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Program.vshost.exe): Loaded 'D:\Programming\Program\Program\bin\x86\Debug\TwainDotNet.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Program.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Program.vshost.exe): Loaded 'D:\Programming\Program\Program\bin\x86\Debug\TwainDotNet.WinFroms.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Program.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Program.vshost.exe): Loaded 'D:\Programming\Program\Program\bin\x86\Debug\Program-CustomDlls.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in TwainDotNet.dll
```

The code it dies on is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using TwainDotNet.TwainNative;
using TwainDotNet.Win32;
using System.Drawing;

namespace TwainDotNet
{
    public class Twain
    {
        DataSourceManager _dataSourceManager;

        public Twain(IWindowsMessageHook messageHook)
        {
            ScanningComplete += delegate { };
            TransferImage += delegate { };

            _dataSourceManager = new DataSourceManager(DataSourceManager.DefaultApplicationId, messageHook);
            _dataSourceManager.ScanningComplete += delegate(object sender, ScanningCompleteEventArgs args)
            {
                ScanningComplete(this, args);
            };
            _dataSourceManager.TransferImage += delegate(object sender, TransferImageEventArgs args)
            {
                TransferImage(this, args);
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Notification that the scanning has completed.
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<ScanningCompleteEventArgs> ScanningComplete;

        public event EventHandler<TransferImageEventArgs> TransferImage;

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts scanning.
        /// </summary>
        public void StartScanning(ScanSettings settings)
        {
            _dataSourceManager.StartScan(settings);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Shows a dialog prompting the use to select the source to scan from.
        /// </summary>
        public void SelectSource()
        {
            _dataSourceManager.SelectSource();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Selects a source based on the product name string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sourceName">The source product name.</param>
        public void SelectSource(string sourceName)
        {
            var source = DataSource.GetSource(
                sourceName,
                _dataSourceManager.ApplicationId,
                _dataSourceManager.MessageHook);

            _dataSourceManager.SelectSource(source);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the product name for the default source.
        /// </summary>
        public string DefaultSourceName
        {
            get
            {
                using (var source = DataSource.GetDefault(_dataSourceManager.ApplicationId, _dataSourceManager.MessageHook))
                {
                    return source.SourceId.ProductName;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a list of source product names.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<string> SourceNames
        {
            get
            {
                var result = new List<string>();
                var sources = DataSource.GetAllSources(
                    _dataSourceManager.ApplicationId,
                    _dataSourceManager.MessageHook);

                foreach (var source in sources)
                {
                    result.Add(source.SourceId.ProductName);
                    source.Dispose();
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Line 21: _dataSourceManager = new DataSourceManager(DataSourceManager.DefaultApplicationId, messageHook);

I have no idea why it dies and the debug message is vague. Any idea's?

Comment: TypeLoadException is telling you (probably) that the assembly where DataSourceManager could not be loaded. So figure out in which assembly this types resides and place this in your bin dir.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was due to which CPU type I was compiling for. I took the code for the TwainDotNet and recompiled it for x86. I then set my master program to compile for x86. It works now.

I had been compiling for AnyCPU. log4net.dll is compiled for x86 and is needed by TwainDotNet. I also think Twain was compiled for x86 but I have no way of telling.

Needless to say, I'm compiling for x86 architecture now.